# Wordpress - connect to OAuth server

Tags: wordpress, oauth

I'm trying to find a way in WordPress to connect to a OAuth server. I found few plugins but they do not have any option to connect with a OAuth server.

Comment: Which one in particular?

Comment: did u tried with this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/oauth2-provider/